# All Prophets apart from the 25 mentioned in Quraan

Tags: prophets, reference-request

Apart form the 25 Prophets mentioned in Quraan, how can we find at least the names of the other Prophets and mabybe some story of theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allah (SWT) said in the Qur'an that there were Messengers before the Prophet (PBUH) that He (SWT) **did not relate to the Prophet (PBUH) their stories**.

[image]

So, if you don't find names/stories of those Prophets in the Qur'an and the Sunnah, there is no other place where you can find them.

**Allah knows best.**

Answer (score 0):

Only reliable source we have is Qur'an and Saheeh Ahadith. In hadith a few more mentioned sometimes deliberately w/o a name. Find out more? then study hadiths ;)